# Keycloak 401 on getAccessToken()

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

sometimes on production I have an following error, its while doing registration, after getting email to confirm account, there is special client for that, so they must be good otherwise other clients wont register

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.KeycloakAdminService.getUserFromKeycloakByUsername(KeycloakAdminService.java:35)
```

on calling this:

```
AccessTokenResponse accessToken = keycloakUserReader.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
```

timeouts config:
[image]

I can not reproduce it locally.. not sure what can be the reason, maybe someone here also had similar issues with Keycloak ?

thanks!

Comment: Can you try to get the access token but without the credentials or with the wrong credentials

Comment: @dreamcrash credentials are there, its while doing registration, after getting email to confirm account, there is special client for that, so they must be good otherwise other clients wont register

Comment: Did you try to add some log in the getUserFromKeycloakByUsername method, to get more information

Comment: its only on prod, all what I have atm